# Cannot start Database from pfile

Tags: oracle

I tried to set Sga_target to 2G but getting an error that its too low, I start the database with my pfile.

I'm getting the below errors:

> `ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error ORA-01092:
>   ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced ORA-14694: database
>   must in UPGRADE mode to begin MAX_STRING_SIZE migration

Incident details in:

> D:\APP\ORAADMIN\diag\rdbms\naghitrn\naghitrn\incident\incdir_396077\naghitrn_ora_146628_i396077.trc
>   2018-10-18T19:37:26.001820+11:00 opiodr aborting process unknown ospid
>   (146628) as a result of ORA-603 2018-10-18T19:37:26.024820+11:00
>   ORA-603 : opitsk aborting process License high water mark = 4
>   2018-10-18T19:37:26.026820+11:00 USER (ospid: 146628): terminating the
>   instance due to error 14694 2018-10-18T19:37:28.030825+11:00 GEN0
>   (ospid: 139468): terminating the instance due to error 14694
>   2018-10-18T19:37:33.127823+11:00 USER (ospid: 148464): terminating the
>   instance due to error 14694 2018-10-18T19:37:33.149840+11:00 PMON
>   (ospid: 147784): terminating the instance due to error 14694
>   2018-10-18T19:37:38.361821+11:00 Instance terminated by PMON, pid =
>   147784`

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to state which is your problem and how to solve it... the problem is not due to sga target, you have simply start your db in upgrade mode using this command:

```
startup upgrade
```

instead of the usual startup

Comment: its throwing me the error that sga_target is too small that why im starting with pfile with 4G sga target

Comment: @MaryAnnCuadrasal the error you posted here tell us "ORA-14694: database must in UPGRADE mode to begin MAX_STRING_SIZE migration" no reference to sga

Comment: im getting below error:         'SQL> startup upgrade;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2147483648 bytes
Fixed Size                  8748912 bytes
Variable Size             603979920 bytes
Database Buffers         1526726656 bytes
Redo Buffers                8028160 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-14693: The MAX_STRING_SIZE parameter must be EXTENDED.
Process ID: 11288
Session ID: 252 Serial number: 2841'

Comment: @MaryAnnCuadrasal have you tried setting MAX_STRING_SIZE=EXTENDED in your pfile?